# Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This Error i got from lastError.js file which i have not event called in my html page.

```
 var errorMessage = name + ': ' + message;
  if (stack != null && stack != '')
    errorMessage += '\n' + stack;
  console.error(errorMessage);<--this line gives the error
```

Commented the whole js in my code still get this error in console..
is this possible caused due to any extension i have not added any new extension today.Started getting this error today.

2)Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined 
 This is the second error which i get from event_bindings.js

Comment: btw all these in source panell show that they are loaded from (no domain) what does that mean

Comment: This type of error is indeed typically related to one of the intalled extensions

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.
I checked my installed extensions and when I disabled the:
**Google Chrome to Phone Extension 2.3.1** 
the error stopped.

If you don't have this extension installed, try to go over the installed extensions and disable one by one clicking the refresh between every one. You might found another extension that cause this error.

Good luck.

Comment: i stopped getting these error after just few days back i guess it got updated thanks anyways

Comment: I had the same thing, for me the offending plugin was: WASP - Web Analytics Solution Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

for me addblock chrome plugin was causing the error